# plusService->people->get возвращает Error calling GET (Google Plus API)

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

Ребята, подскажите, как проверить, существует ли User в Google Plus?

Использую библиотеку [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master).

На запрос

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey(env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'));
$plusService = new Google_Service_Plus($client);    
$plusService->people->get('116253547259508831292')
```

возвращает

> Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/116253547259508831292?key=myAPIKey:
>   (404) Not Found.

Или, хотя бы, как обработать эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел бегло, чтобы помочь в решении вашего вопроса

1. $plusService->people это класс `Google_Service_Plus_People_Resource` который унаследован от `Google_Service_Resource`

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Plus.php#L400

Вы используете метод ->get

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Plus.php#L413

Который в свою очердь использует метод $this->call('get', array($params), "Google_Service_Plus_Person") от родителя Google_Service_Resource

Смотрим Google_Service_Resource
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/37adb8a6f4d4b27b9900d62d67bf1d54995a755c/src/Google/Service/Resource.php#L77

Смотрим докблок

`@return Google_Http_Request|expectedClass
@throws Google_Exception`

Следовательно что бы обработать ошибку (исключение) то используем try/catch на Google_Exception

Response посмотрите обычным var_dump, а еще лучше возьмите удобную библиотеку к примеру : https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper

Btw: Внимание обратите на HTTP Response Code

404: Это нет пользователя